# Rewrite all PHP urls to a specific url in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

How can I rewrite all PHP requests to a single, specific url?

For example these urls

> https://somesite.com/thing.php
>
> https://somesite.com/dir/ (contains index.php)

Would be redirected to this:
https://somesite.com/dir/someotherthing.php

I also want to keep the client-side URL untouched:

For example https://somesite.com/thing.php should still be the same URL instead of instantly changed to https://somesite.com/dir/someotherthing.php

Another question, would `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP still be the client-side's request URL when I do this? And if not, how can I pass it to https://somesite.com/dir/someotherthing.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect the client without touching client-side URL via server-side.

Use AJAX for that. The behavior you are looking for is similar in some ways to the way a SPA application interacts with an API.